# Support regional language in android speech synthesizer

Tags: android, speech

Does anyone have  idea about adding a regional language into android speech synthesizer? I want to add a language support in speech recognition.

Comment: What language are you interested in? In general you can't add language to google synthesizer since it's a proprietary product, however, you can add your language to third-party packages like espeak.

Comment: i want to add regional languages of India. Please tell me if you know the method to crate speech syntehsizer.